# How to include the methods from on class in another

Tags: c#, class

I want to me able to include a bunch of methods from one main class into several Forms.
Example

```
class Master{
    public void kill(){
         this.Hide()
    }
 }

 class b : Form{
      //What must I do so that class 'b' can call kill, an it would mean that b would close
 }
```

First i thought if Master inherits Form, then b can inherit Master, but that failed. Not a clue, really struggling, all comments welcome. Thank you!

### Edit

Ok, there are lots of functions and variables which need to be copied into the form. This is why i wanted something similar to sub classing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "but that failed"

Answer (score 1):

Make `kill` into an extension method.

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static void Kill(this Form form)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want it to apply to every form, then you can extend a marker interface and apply it to the applicable forms

```
public interface IKillable
{  }

public static class KillableExtensions
{
    public static void Kill(this IKillable form)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make a master and call it

```
class b : Form{
      //What must i do so that class be can call kill
      Master _master = new Master();

      void Stuff()
      {
         _master.kill();
      }


 }
```

You can also make extension methods....  assuming there is no members of Master that you want to access

Or you could make Master inherit Form, then make b inherit Master

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method from other class by creating its object.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
public class A 
{
   public void myMethod()
   {

   }
}


public class B
{
    A a = new A();            // here 'a' is an object of class 'A'
    a.myMethod(); 
}
```